# Should I use curried function for this?

Tags: scala

I have this code snippet:

```
val chunks = blob.map(_.id).distinct.grouped(100).toSeq 
val output = (for (chunk <- chunks) yield { 
  MyDataStore.batchGet("tablez", chunk.asJava, classOf[TableZ], true).asScala }).flatten
```

I would like to convert this into a general purpose method which takes as parameters `blob.map(_.id).distinct` and `MyDataStore.batchGet("tablez", chunk.asJava, classOf[TableZ], true).asScala`

I am thinking maybe curried function but unsure about syntax.

Just to clarify, `chunks` is a `Seq[Seq[String]]`, `batchGet` returns a `List[T]` where `T` is `tablez`, `output` is `Seq[TableZ]`.

Comment: I can't tell what types you expect these things to have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following will work:

```
def getInGroups[T,U](ids: Seq[T], groupSize: Int = 100)(getter: Seq[T] => Seq[U]): Seq[U] = {
   ids.grouped(groupSize).flatMap{ chunk =>  getter(chunk) }.toSeq
}
```

Call it as

```
getInGroups(blob.map(_.id).distinct){ chunk => 
   MyDataStore.batchGet("tablez", chunk.asJava, classOf[TableZ], true).asScala
}
```